# Telnet connection to devices for c#

Tags: c#, stream, arrays, telnet

I want to telnet program for some cisco devices in our company. I'm using this code:

```
String str = Console.ReadLine();
Stream stm = tcpClient.GetStream();

ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();

byte[] bb = new byte[100];

int k = stm.Read(bb, 0,100);

for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(bb[i])); 
}
```

but it returns just some numbers can you say what is wrong or different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you print byte value, it you want to print the string from those byte try using the below code (instead of the for loop):

```
            byte[] bb = new byte[100];

            int k = stm.Read(bb, 0,100);
            Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bb));
```

You can change the Encoding also, read the [String.Text.Encoding_properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.Encoding_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example the [Ascii encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
  // Create an ASCII encoding.
  Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;

  String decodedString = ascii.GetString(bb);
```

Comment: thanks for help but it returns something like that y1y1 y1#1 how can i change encoding

Comment: im sorry but it is not return anything even y1y1 y1#1

Comment: what do you except to see ?

Comment: i tried to telnet our device an it has to be ask username and password am i doing wrong?

Comment: There are many example for what you are trying to do http://telnetcsharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

Answer (score 0):

You should convert to char or use this:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stm);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```